# is there a panorama or pivot UI control on android similar to the ones on windows phone 7?

Tags: android

does anyone know if there is a UI widget out there for android that is like the windows phone 7 panorama or pivot controls? if not, is there any tutorial that would guide me down the right path in implementing my own?

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I was interested in the Pivot controls also.

Here's the best working resource I've found for Pivot-like functionality: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Or, if you would like to see the official Android Developers' Guide about this, called ViewPager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I entirely get what you want, but looking at [this](http://phone.codeplex.com/) Pivot really is just tabs: take a look at the [Tab Widget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial. Panorama is a bit more tedious: you can try embedding the View you want to pan into a HorizontalScroller. If it is wider than the screen it will let you scroll around horizontally. To get vertical panning as well wrap that with a ScrollView.

Comment: on my motorola atrix, there is a "News & Weather" app. it uses tabs and almost works like a pivot. i like how when you swipe left/right, you see the content of the next view come in smoothly (and the current content go out smoothly). i wonder what view composition is used to accomplish that effect. also, as you are swiping, the current tab is also re-aligned to be centered. how do they do that? lastly, there is the BBC News app, and it also has a pretty slick UI that is like the pivot. to follow the above tutorial is a start, but i want to go beyond that to mimic the pivot/panorama control.

Comment: It is broadly speaking beyond my experience, but I understand you can do stuff like that using View animations. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005547/android-activity-transition-animation-in-activitygroup and http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities and see if they offer any guidance.