# Equivalent of wp7 pivot control on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7

Do iOS and Android have equivalent of WP7 Pivot Control ?

If not how to emulate ? Any sample code to do so ?

Comment: For Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907114/is-there-a-panorama-or-pivot-ui-control-on-android-similar-to-the-ones-on-window

Comment: It is called "tabs" there.